# How can i save Data to a User in Parse?

Tags: uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I want to backup the Data of an UITableView to Parse. First the User logs in. Now every user should have it's own cloud Storage save of their UITableView, but how to upload this UITableView or the UITableViewCell when pressing on a Button (Save)?

Answer (score 2):

You can create separate Model objects for populating each cell of the **UITableView** . Saving objects into parse is very well in explained in the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS):

Also take a look at this tutorial if you still need more explanation:
[Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/)

Parse is just a `backend` which allows you to save data by calling their functions.
The concept of parse is to show the data in your app by using their api and database.

An example to save a PFObject (A parse object) in the parse database:

```
let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject") // Create the PFObject with the classname/tablename on parse
testObject["foo"] = "bar" // set the property "foo" to "bar"
// save the object in background (not on the gui thread to prevent lags on the UI)
testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  println("Object has been saved.")
}
```

ATTENTION: Before to be able to call these functions and create there objects you need to import the Parse Library and initialize your app to parse.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but how can i assign an user to this PFObject?

Comment: Do i need to do it like this, or is there an simpler solution to save and get data for a specific user `PFObject *game= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Game"];
[game setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"createdBy"];`