# Ideas to store an TableView for different Users on Parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I have an application where the user needs to sign in first. Now in my application there is an table view which can be filled with different events for example: a user adds an Title for a new event and an yellow icon. Now the Title and the yellow icon appears in the tableview.

Now i want the app to sync with Parse so that this user can see it's Title and it's yellow icon on every device he's logged in.

I'm sorry that i need to ask, i hope you can help me :/

[image: The Table View that should sync with Parse]

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question you asked 7h ago and got answers for it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741408/how-can-i-save-data-to-a-user-in-parse

Comment: You are completely right but I thought I have messed up my description of my problem so I asked you what you would do to solve this?!

Comment: You should have edited your answer instead of posting a new one. Give me some time to provide you an example since this question is very broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is already a lot of content regarding your question and the `Parse SDK` is very well documented.

For example have a look at this: [Save App Data to Parse Backend](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/)

You should do the following steps:

- Create an App on Parse
- Create User Table
- Create AppData Table
- Reference the User with the AppData entry via column type : "Pointer"
- Whenever a entry was added to your tableview or whenever the app is closed save the current data to your parse backend
- Whenever the tableview is shown or whenever your application starts retrieve the information from your Parse backend and show them in your tableview accordingly

I hope the link I gave you can give you some insight, however nobody knows whether you are coding in `Swift` or `Objective-C` because you added both tags.

If you need more information on how to design your backend in order to retrieve the right entries for the specific user I recommend reading this:
[find-all-objects-belonging-to-a-user-with-objectid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880781/parse-com-find-all-objects-belonging-to-a-user-with-objectid) 
or reading about `relational queries` in the `Parse SDK.`

Comment: I have finally got it, thanks @unverschaemt he has helped me a lot :D Also I have found a great video on youtube -> [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x70G_LPlW60)